# Using ConfigurationBuilder in C# .NET Framework where did my App Service settings go?

Tags: c#, azure, app-config, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to combine a *environment-specific variables in source code* to an existing configuration of an *App.config-file* and *AppSettings and ConnectionStrings in Azure App Services* for an Azure WebJob (.NET Framework). Having all environment variables in App Services can be quite time-consuming when making changes.

After going through a bunch of blogs and posts on the subject of App.config-tranformations and Azure WebJobs it seems like adding a ConfigurationBuilder is fairly recent way to override environment specific (non-secret) settings. If I'm not mistaken it was added in .NET 4.7.1. It seemed more promising than SlowCheetah and scripting.

But after adding a custom ConfigurationBuilder (similarly to mentioned on link 1) **the app settings specified in app service were no longer included in the result**. I ended up with only entries from app.config-file and custom ConfigurationBuilder. Do I need to retrieve these app setting while making custom entries in the configuration entries? Or should I expand the EnvironmentVariables and modify those XmlNode-entries?

1. https://jeffreyfritz.com/2017/11/modern-configuration-for-asp-net-4-7-1-with-configurationbuilders/
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out there are a few things to consider and some assumptions to be made before had a possible route to go. I ended up writing my own configuration builder with help of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=netframework-4.8).

Given that .NETFramework is used and not AspNetCore (specifically .NETFramework 4.7.1 in this case). It seems that App Services provisioned by Azure does use some kind of configuration builder out-of-the-box. It seems like `Web.config` without any specified configuration builder will include all Azure App Services settings. It will even add settings that aren't present in the `Web.config`. So scaffolding isn't used; This would probably have made things a tad bit easier to grasp, but Microsoft probably had good reasons for not implementing things that way. Adding a configuration builder of your own will make any settings read from Azure App Services to not be read anymore. Probably, I'm assuming, because you just replaced a "hidden" configuration builder and need to do this work yourself now.

Looking into the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders/tree/master/src) I did another relevant discovery that help me quite a bit in writing my own configuration builder. There seems to be two typical modes of operation in how configuration builders work: Greedy or "strict". I would advise against using both at the same time. A greedy mode implies that all settings found in, let's say, environment variables are added regardless of whether the key was initially present in `Web.config`. A "strict" mode implies it only replaces the value for keys present from the start.

I ended up reading relevant settings from the environment variables. But it was a bit tricky to find solid documentation of the appropriate prefixes used (it is possible to read all the variables though). But the most common ones [are roughly](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/app-service/configure-common) (I think):

- `APPSETTING_` (believe these correspond to App Services settings, if I recall correctly)
- `SQLServerSQLCONNSTR_`
- `SQLAZURECONNSTR_`

Anyway, I my particular scenario I was running both an App Service Web App and a WebJob in the same slot. Having settings from the Web App appended for the WebJob seemed unattractive and unnecessary. So I wrote a "strict" configuration builder that cascades all the setting in a careful manner from the sources. This means any setting specified in Azure App Services would also have to be defined in `Web.config`. If no such setting next any transformed values for a chosen configuration was included. Lastly, the default value value in `Web.config` was used.

In summary, *if you're writing your own configuration builder in .NETFramework*, you may need to do a little work to include the App Service app settings or connection strings. You might want to investigate the `ConfigurationBuilder`-class and their respective methods `ProcessConfigurationSection` for typed classes or `ProcessRawXml` and perhaps checkout some [real world examples](https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders/blob/master/src/AzureAppConfig/AzureAppConfigurationBuilder.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following links, it seems they address issues similar to what you are describing:

- [Azure App Settings don't override external config files in WebJobs #1847](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1847)
- [Read web.config XML in Azure Web Jobs #1571](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1571)

Hope it helps!